# Embeded iframe change position of its container

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a problem with iframe tag ([check the code](http://jsfiddle.net/QVEFq/1/)). I embed Youtube/Vimeo video inside `div` container (`display: inline-block`), but it change its container. See last two in demo (resize result window for showing two or more `div`s inline).
I tried with changing `div` with `span` or `li`, but it doesn't help. What  shoud I do?

Comment: I can't see any iFrames or videos in that fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I have sent wrong fiddle.

Comment: Try now. I'm sorry, I sent wrong fiddle.

Comment: Are you expecting the divs to be side-by-side or to be under each other?

Comment: They are side-by-side, but it can't be show in result window without resizing. When they are under each other there is no problem.

Comment: So you want them to be simply under each other? If that's the case then just remove display:inline-block

Comment: No, I don't want to be under each other... I add `inline-block` to be side-by-side

Comment: @BillyMoat just `display: inline;` won't work?

Comment: @Mr. Alien - I wasn't exactly sure what he was trying to achieve here. So yeah, it turns out that display:inline would've worked!

Comment: @BillyMoat Me too, moreover I was not able to see his fiddle perfectly on my 18" monitor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem is that the containing divs with videos are not aligning correctly with the others. (No?) Changing display to block and floating left fixes that.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/QVEFq/4/

Comment: Thanks! It works. I have just added `float: left` and it works!